# Listbox mousedown and doubleclick

Tags: c#

I am not able to get MouseDoubleClick event fired for my ListBox. I have added MouseDown
Event. Every time I double click MouseDown Event is fired Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of events fired, when you press a mouse button over a control. They are fired in this order:

- MouseDown
- MouseClick
- MouseUp

The DoubleClick event will be fired, if you double click the control in a certain time span. So the event should be raised. If you do something "magic" in your MouseDown event, it is possible that the MouseDoubleClick will not be raised.

If you need more help, post the MouseDownEvent code and tag your question wether it is in WinForms or WPF.

**Edit**:

If you have a breakpoint in the MouseDown Event and you are running your code in debugger, the MouseDoubleClick will not be catched by the debugger. Debugging UI events is not very easy...

Comment: @ Thanks Fischermaen for your comments on winForms

 private void listBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int indexOfItem = listBox.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (indexOfItem != -1)  string
            {
                listBox.DoDragDrop(indexOfItem.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

Comment: I Got it fixed used the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.aspx

Comment: @Razack: For Drag and Drop purposes there are different events available. Drag and drop is handled by the runtime, you just have "to feed" it.

Comment: @ Fischermaen: My purpose of drag and drop is entirely inside the list box just to reorder the items. For that I am using following event 1. MouseDown 2.DragOver and 3. DragDrop .. This Mousedown for darg and drop was preventing Double click

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a work-around to avoid this issue and found the following. This will allow double click events to fire when you are using the mouse down event as well.

```
private void myControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 1)
      {
           //do my mouse down stuff
      }
}
```